# Adding Subclass to a Base Class Vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

So I'm desperately trying to figure out how to add subclass objects to a base class vector in C/C++. I've looked around and found that I need to use pointers and memory addresses. Beyond that, I still haven't found an answer.

The example is simple. I have an appointment book that has a series of monthly, daily and one-time appointments. These need to be store in a vector.

Also, if someone can refer me to a good learning source for pointers--that would be appreciated. Good Learning Source in general. I have a professor where 70% of his class has dropped the course and I need a passing grade. T.T

```
#pragma once
#include "Appointment.h"
#include "Daily.h"
#include "Monthly.h"
#include "Onetime.h"

using namespace std; 

int main() {
    vector<Appointment *> appointmentBook;
    bool loop = true; 
    string input; 

    while (loop) {
        cout << "Enter the kind of appointment or q to quit: (d/m/o/q)" << endl; 
        cin >> input; 

        if (input == "d") {
            appointmentBook.push_back(Daily().read());
        } else if(input == "m") {

        }
        else if (input == "o") {

        }
        else {
            exit(0); 
        }
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In particular, I see zero "subclass" types. If we don't know your exact problem, we can't help.

Comment: Daily, Monthly and Onetime are all subclasses of Appointment. Hence the Appointment vector. I didn't add  the code to prevent additional information being not needed as the code for those classes are error free. I'm literally just trying to figure out how to store subclasses in a base class vector.

Comment: @Ricco What does `Daily().read()` return?

Comment: Ricco, it's your job to extract a minimal but complete example from your code *before* posting here! Since you wanted to skip irrelevant parts, what about the while-loop? How is that relevant? Or the nonportable `#pragma once`? Also, what is that "C/C++" think that you mention?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the following *might* work:

```
vector<Appointment> apps;
AppointmentChild child;
apps.push_back(child);
```

But here you would have *copies* of your objects in the vector, which is most likely not what you want. Additionally, as @TheUndeadFish mentioned in the comments, such copies could also be sliced, thus losing the data stored in the derived class and possibly having some other troubles.

---

And now the pointers are what you could use:

```
vector<Appointment*> apps;
auto child = new AppointmentChild;
apps.push_back(child);

delete child; // Don't forget to delete the object, when it is no more in use.
```

---

But a better option might be the `shared_ptr`:

```
vector<shared_ptr<Appointment>> apps;
auto child = make_shared<AppointmentChild>();
apps.push_back(child);
```

Here you don't need to care about deleting the allocated object, `shared_ptr` will do it for you.

Comment: `vector<Appointment>` would NOT work. Trying to put any derived object into that would slice it while copying, thus ending up with base objects.

Comment: @TheUndeadFish Fixed. Thanks and sorry for that, during 10 years in C++ I never faced the problem with slicing.